# How to log all microservices logs in a single Log-file using springboot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have 5 web applications which I developed using `Springboot`(A,B,C,D and E).
Below are the flow of 2 calls

First Flow:

`A's Controllers --> A's Service --> B's Controller --> B'Service --> C's Controller --> C's Service --> C's Dao --> DB`

SecondFlow:

`A's Controllers --> A's Service --> D's Controller --> D'Service --> B's Controller --> B'Service --> C's Controller --> C's Service --> C's Dao --> DB`

Once fetch/push data from/into the DB then the corresponding methods are returning some value. For each and every method logging the status (input details and returning status). I am able to see logs in each service separately. But I want to see complete one **request-response(A's controller request to A's controller response) cycle logs in one file**.

How Can I achieve it?

Comment: can you try with https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth

Answer (score 2):

This is a ver bad idea, but let's take a step back and look at the problem instead of guessing a solution.

You have multiple applications that collaborate together to execute (distributed) transactions. You need to trace those interactions to see your dataflow. This is very useful for many reasons so it's correct that you care about it. It is also correct to collect all you log entries in a single sink, even if it won't be a file because it is not well suited to manage prodcution workloads. A typical scenario that many organization implements is the following

1. Each application send logs to files or standard output
2. For each node of you infrastructure there is an agent that reads that streams, does some basic conversion (eg. translates log entries in a common format) and send data to a certain sink
3. The sink is a database, the best technology option is a DBMS without strict requirements about data schema (you are storing everything in a single huge table after all) and transactional properites (if the data are logs, you are fine with an optimistic concurrency control). You also want some tool that is more good at reads than writes and have good performance in complex searches to drill down a large amount of structured data
4. a Dashboard to read logs, make searches and even create dashboard with synthetic stats about events

BONUS: use a buffer to manage load spikes

There are precise tools to do the job and they are

1. logstash/beats/fluentd
2. Elasticsearch....what else? ;)
3. Kibana, the favourite Elasticsearch client
   BONUS: rabbimq/kafka/otherMessageBroker or Redis

but you still miss a step

Suppose you call a REST API, something simple like a POST /users/:userId/cart

1. API Gateway receives your request with a JWT
2. API Gateway calls Authentication-service to validate and decode the JWT
3. API Gateway calls Authorization-service to check if the client as right to perform the request
4. API Gateway calls User-service to find :userId
5. User-Service calls Cart-service to add the product on :userId cart
6. Cart-Service calls Notification-Service to decide whether is needed to send a notification for the completed task
7. Notification-Service calls Push-Gateway to invoke an external push notification service

....and back

to not get lost in this labyrinth you NEED just one thing: the correlation  ID

- Correlation IDs attach a unique ID to all interaction beetween these microservices (headers in HTTP calls or AMQP messages, for instance) and your custom log library (because you've already built a custom logging library and shared it among all the teams) capture this ID to include it in every log entry wrote in the context of the single request processed from each of those microservices. You can even add that correlation ID in the client response, catch it if the respone carry out an error code and perform a query on your logs DB to find all the entries with the given correlation ID. If the system clock works, they will be retrieved in the correct time order and you will be able to reconstruct the dataflow

Distributed Systems make everything more complicate and add a lot of overhead on things that we ever done before, but if you put in your pocket the right tools to manage the complexity, you can see the benefits

Answer (score 0):

you can implement central logging system like:

The ELK stack (Elastic Search, Logstash and Kibana) for Centralized Logging.